# CSS Overflow property isn't working on navigation bar links

Tags: html, css, portfolio

I've been working on my portfolio and I came across this video where you hover the navigation links and they make an upward transition. [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wsTBAN0j2Y)

The css overflow method which I've applied according to the video that will remove duplicate navlinks (About me, Tools etc.) but this isn't working for me and I can't figure out why.

Relevant HTMl:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Protfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
        <nav>
          <div class="space1">
            <div class="centered-content nav-logo">Logo</div>
            <div class="centered-content empty-space1">
              <!--empty space-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="space2">
            <div class="centered-content empty-space2">
              <!--empty space-->
            </div>
            <div class="centered-content nav-links">
              <ul class="centered-content">
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    
                  <span>About Me</span>
                  <span>About Me</span>
                </a>
              </li> 
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    <span> Contact</span>
                  <span> Contact</span>
                </a>
              </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    <span>Blog</span>
                    <span>Blog</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                  <span>Projects</span>
                  <span>Projects</span>
                </a>
              </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    <span>Tools</span>
                    <span>Tools</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="intro-container">
       <div class="intro-para">
            <h1>Greetings All!!</h1>
                Intro-content</div>
           <div class="centered-content intro-image">
               the image goes 
           </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    /* ADDITION */

.centered-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  
  /* END */
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color:peachpuff;
    font-family: roboto;
    background-repeat: space;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  nav {
    display: flex;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: crimson;
  }
  
  .space1 {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    
  }
  
  .nav-logo {
    display: flex;
    
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .empty-space1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .space2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .empty-space2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    
  }
  
  .nav-links ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    /* REMOVED! */
    /* height: 100%; */

    
  }
  
  .nav-links ul li{
    position: relative;

  }
  .nav-links ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0 .4em;
    color: black;  
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }

  .nav-links ul li a span{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    flex-direction: column;  
  }

  .nav-links ul li a:hover span{

  }

.intro-container{
      display: flex;
      padding: .2% .3% 0 .3% ;
  }

  .intro-para{    
      background-color:salmon;
      width: 50%;
      
  }

  .intro-image{
      width: 50%;
    background-color: lightskyblue;
  }
```

[image: Relevant Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element should have a height. You have not provided height or max-height attribute for the `.nav-links ul li a` selector as given in the Youtube video link you provided.

Comment: Hey, I tried that, even now. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you are using Chrome try checking dev tools under Computed to see what height your element has. If it's 0px means the height is not set. Try changing setting height attribute from dev tools and see if your element gets non-zero height.

Comment: I tried it right now. It's set to 100% height in my code and shows the same on dev tool too.

Comment: Okay, I went through your code and found the issue, your element has height 43 so both lines are showing. You can try giving a height of 24px to the li or you can give height 43px to ul and 50% to li. In the Youtube video the person had given height 40px which must be close to half of the elements original height.

Comment: Did you try giving height: 24px; to li and overflow: hidden;

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. It worked. Would you please tell me how did you come to know about my elements having height of 43?

Comment: Hi, good to know I was of help. I took your code and checked in Chrome dev tools as I mentioned. I selected the ul element using element selection mode, which can be activated by clicking the arrow icon on top-left. Then after selecting the 'li' element, I went to 'Computed' tab and checked the height there. The 'Computed' tab shows you values for attributes like height, display etc, for selected component.

Comment: You can check out tutorials for Chrome dev tool on Youtube. It's really helpful for testing & debugging web apps.